How to install a locally developed python wheel file as part of a native Snowflake app
I am trying to install a local python wheel file as part of a Snowflake native app.
I tried the steps in the following article:
https://medium.com/snowflake/introducing-simple-workflow-for-using-python-packages-in-snowpark-928f667ff1aa
But, I keep getting the following error:
093082 (42601): 01b44791-0102-aab9-0000-0002b61281f9: Failed to execute setup script:
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 34 at position 0 : SQL compilation error: Package 'perpetual' is not supported.

The only difference is that they use a package from pypi in the medium article but I am trying to install a local wheel file.
Is there a way to install locally developed python wheel file as part of a native Snowflake app?

There isn't enough context in your question to give a definite answer. The following code works to incorporate a Python wheel file in a Python UDF. Perhaps you can use a similar technique in your code. First, the wheel file must be uploaded into a Snowflake stage. Then you append the wheel file to the Python system path.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ULID()
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
HANDLER = 'ulid'
IMPORTS = ('@PYTHON_PACKAGES/python_ulid-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl')
AS '
import sys

import_dir = sys._xoptions.get("snowflake_import_directory")
sys.path.append(import_dir + "python_ulid-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl")
from ulid import ULID

def ulid():
  a_ulid = ULID()
  return str(a_ulid)
';

